# Exception not handled IOError

Tags: python

I can't seem to figure out why my code can't handle the exception of reporting an error if my web server does not contain a file. In the directory of my server I have the code for it and HelloWorld.html. For other files it should report an error. I'm looking through my code and it would seem that it is reading any file and just saying that its contents are blank without actually throwing an error that the file is not on the server. What is going on here?

```
#Tasks: Create a socket, bind to a specific address and port, send and receive an HTTP        packet.
#Description: Web server should handle one HTTP request at a time. So the serve closes its TCP connection after response.
#Accept and parse the HTTP request, get the requested file from the server (i.e.   HelloWorld.html), create a response
#message with the requested file and header lines, then send the response to the client.
#Error handling: If file not found then send HTTP "404 Not Found" Message back to client.

#import socket module: here we are using a low-level networking class from Python
from socket import * 

#create the socket that belongs to the server.
#AF_INTET represents the address families and protocols.
#SOCK_STREAM represents the socket type
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) 

#Prepare a server socket 

#Define variable for serverPort; we'll use the one in the helper page of the book
serverPort = 51350
#Define host address
serverHost = ''

#Bind the socket to the local host machine address and port
serverSocket.bind((serverHost, serverPort))

#Listen for TCP connections from the client
serverSocket.listen(1)

#Verify setup for receiving
print 'Server is ready to receive'

while True: 
 #Establish the connection 
 print 'Ready to serve...' 
 #When the server receive a request from the client it must establish a new connectionSocket and begin taking in the data.
 connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
 try: 
 #Take data from connectionSocket and place in message.
 #.recvfrom doesn't work because it expects data and return address variables.
    message = connectionSocket.recv(1024) 

    #uncomment for header information
    #print message

     #parse the message
    filename = message.split()[1] 
    f = open(filename[1:]) 
    outputdata = f.read();

 #Send one HTTP header line into socket 
    connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n')

 #Send the content of the requested file to the client 
    for i in range(0, len(outputdata)): 
        connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i]) 

    connectionSocket.close() 

 except IOError:

 #Send response message for file not found 
    connectionSocket.send('404 Not Found')
    connectionSocket.close()

 #Close client socket 
 serverSocket.close()
```

Comment: fyi, http 1.1 requires Content-Length or custom Transfer-Encoding. what you are doing here is http 1.0 or perhaps even 0.9 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need `"HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n"` instead of `"404 Not Found"`.

Also, you seem to close `serverSocket` within the loop, thus next `accept()` fails.

Comment: Yeah, just changed that. It's not throwing an error at f = open(filename[1:]) I tried verifying the name of filename[1:] and it is the name after '/' character in URL. hmmm not sure how python jumps to except block.

Comment: okay so your problem is not the handling of exception, rather why exception is triggered...

Comment: Well, the exception should be triggered. Then I should be able to see some sort of message on the client side (web browser) of "404 Not Found"

Comment: Fixed it. I guess the exception was being thrown properly but I needed to set outputdata ='404 Not Found' and then output that message to the screen.